# How to code in python this situation, combining two duplicate rows that have one cell different

Tags: python

I need to code this situation by python with most performant way because My data is about 338 000 row.

I want to group my duplicated rows to get the following  result (table 2)

ps : column SSS will be dropped and create n column that represents the total number of values that SSS contain

```
aaa     bbb     ccc      SSS

1       mmm     qq       S1
1       mmm     qq       S4
2       kkk     aa       S3
3       bbb     ee       S1
3       bbb     ee       S2
3       bbb     ee       S4
4       xxx     tt       S3
```

Result that i need to obtain

```
aaa     bbb     ccc      S1     S2    S3     S4

1       mmm     qq       1      0      0      1
2       kkk     aa       0      0      1      0
3       bbb     ee       1      1      0      1 
4       xxx     tt       0      0      1      0
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you are using pandas, `pivot_table` could help here:

```
df['tot'] = 0      # add a column to have something to count

pd.pivot_table(df, index=['aaa','bbb','ccc'], columns='SSS', aggfunc='count', fill_value=0)
            tot         
SSS          S1 S2 S3 S4
aaa bbb ccc             
1   mmm qq    1  0  0  1
2   kkk aa    0  0  1  0
3   bbb ee    1  1  0  1
4   xxx tt    0  0  1  0
```

Comment: Hi serge, I try your solution but i get that problem : ValueError: Grouper and axis must be same length . ps: ye I use DataFrame of pandas